# How to properly align circle icon with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve something like this inside a bootstrap column (I don't care much about the styles, but the alignment):

[image: what i'm trying to achieve]

Basically, what's I've tried so far is this:

```
<div class="circle">NA</div>
<div class="author">
  <p>Some text</p>
 <p><strong>Should appear here</strong></p>
</div>
```

where `circle` is:

```
.circle {
  float: left;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #66fbd1;
}
```

Also I've applied a lesser line-height:

```
.author {
    line-height: 50%;
}
```

I've tried floating the circle div to the left, however, I get this:

[image]

I am not really sure if:

a) Floating is the right way to go here, considering the fact the icon and the text should be "centered" along the vertical axis

b) If I did accomplish this with floating, how would I make the text more vertically aligned with the icon? Is it just a matter of adjusting the right `margin-top`?

Btw, I know I could solve some of these issues with Flexbox, however, I'm not allowed to use it here.

Comment: Can you use `inline-block`?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4/3? If 4 you could wrap in a column with `align-middle` as the `author` and `circle` class. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use `flexbox`, `inline-block` might be a solution for you. When you use `float`, vertical align is ignored. But it is not ignored when using `display: inline-block`. Try this:

```css
.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #66fbd1;
  vertical-align:middle;
} 

.author {
  line-height: 40%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">NA</div>
<div class="author">
  <p>Some text</p>
 <p><strong>Should appear here</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `display: table;` ? :)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">NA</div>
  <div class="author">
    <p>Some text</p>
   <p><strong>Should appear here</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle,
.author{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if text will be large and dynamic then have different approach. Have many ways but based your markup you can apply following CSS code:

```
.circle {
  float: left;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #66fbd1;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
}
.author {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  line-height:20px; 
}
.author p {
  margin: 0;
}
```